# what is the VB6.FontChangeName alternative in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I have migrated VB6 to VB.Net using wizard tool and below is the one of the property that being migrated. the sprSpread is the far pint spread control reference.

```
Public Property FontName() As String
    Get
        FontName = sprSpread.Font.Name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        sprSpread.Font = VB6.FontChangeName(sprSpread.Font, Value)
        RaiseEvent FontNameChange()
    End Set
End Property
```

What is the Vb.Net alternative for VB6.FontChangeName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the properties of the `Font` class are read-only, when you need to change the property of a font in .NET, you need to create a whole new `Font` object.  For instance:

```
' Create a new font with the same size and style as before, but with a different name
sprSpread.Font = New Font(Value, sprSpread.Font.Size, sprSpread.Font.Style)
```

Comment: The OP did not explain his problem well enough.  The FontChangeName() method from Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility he uses now already creates a Font object.  The real problem is that he still uses the olden ActiveX control, it requires a different kind of font object.